# Selecting rows in a CSV file based on column value

Tags: csv

I have a CSV file with 4 columns: Itemname,Value,Description and component which is quite huge.

I have to generate  a template from the above CSV file that displays only the rows of the specified component(say component='abc' which is the search criterion)

Comment: Unless you edit your question to make it relevant to *nix, this will probably moved to [so] and/or closed.

Comment: @Anthon how is this not relevant to *nix? As Ignacio's answer shows, `awk` is perfect for this.

Comment: @tendon I don't see why `awk` is perfect for this. How does awk e.g. determine the separating character used in the CSV?. This doesn't have to be the [comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), something that e.g. Ignacio assumes). This now seems more a generic programming question that belongs on [so] (if not already answered there), which is why I warned the OP.

Comment: @tendon see the top answer...https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80472/311307

Answer (score 10):

Assuming there are no embedded commas, awk is perfect for this.

```
awk -F , '$4 == "abc" { print }' input.csv
```

Comment: 'print' is the default action, so you may just omit it.

Comment: the separating character for CSV is not always a comma, e.g. not with the defaults for some versions of Excel.

Comment: Replacing the comma with something else is very, very easy.

Answer (score 7):

I used another tool in the csvkit: `csvgrep`.

```
$ csvgrep -c 4 -m "abc" data.csv > test.csv
```

This is the resulting contents of the file `test.csv`:

```
Itemname,Value,Description,Component
33,34,35,abc
```

`-c` is to designate the column to look in. you can also use the header, just make sure you spell it exactly the same, capitals matter:

```
$ csvgrep -c Component -m "abc" data.csv > test.csv

Itemname,Value,Description,Component
33,34,35,abc
```

and `-m` is match pattern, I'm pretty sure there is a way to use regular expressions if you want to get more in-depth in your matching. then it gets put in a new file named `test.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

With the following `data.csv`:

```
Itemname,Value,Description,Component
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16
17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24
25,26,27,28
29,30,31,32
33,34,35,abc
37,38,39,40
41,42,43,44
45,46,47,48
49,50,51,52
53,54,55,56
57,58,59,60
61,62,63,64
65,66,67,68
69,70,71,72
73,74,75,76
77,78,79,80
81,82,83,84
85,86,87,88
89,90,91,92
93,94,95,96
97,98,99,100
```

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvsql --query "SELECT * FROM data WHERE Component = 'abc'" data.csv
Itemname,Value,Description,Component
33,34,35,abc
```